# Do I have to unsubscribe from completed observable in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

If an observable completes, do I still have to unsubscribe / dispose (in RxJS) the observable to remove the Observer (prevent memory leaks) or is this handled internally by Rxjs once a onComplete or onError event occurs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41334931/6680611

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Subject.complete() unsubscribe all listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452979/does-subject-complete-unsubscribe-all-listeners)

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to unsubscribe from an observable you know has completed.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/topromise.js) of the RxJS toPromise() function, you'll see a subscribe, but no unsubscribe. That's because it is not necessary, you know the observable is completed.